# Serial json_decode due to memory limit

Tags: php, json

I have a large json file (7.3MB) that I try to json_decode and it fails due to memory limit (Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted). Is there a way to decode json file serially, with one object/node at a time?

Comment: Have you thought of something like this `ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');` ?

Comment: With a custom parser yes, json_decode is going to read the entire string. Although if you are going to keep the entire resulting object in memory anyway, you may not be saving enough memory.

Comment: Depends on the structure. If it were an array of objects, then resuming the decoding in level 1 would be trivial with any parser. PEARs Services_Json or upgradephp/json_decode certainly could be hacked for such. Iteratively parsing nested structures is more cumbersome, due to recursive manner in which JSON parsers usually are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose in theory you could write some logic to parse characters off the beginning and ending of a string, iteratively reducing the string size in memory while building up the object/array representation, but that would be a serious pain.

Why not just increase your memory limits, or if this is some JSON that needs to be decoded frequently (i.e. with each request to a web application) you ought to consider breaking it apart into more usage components.

Comment: This is more of a theoretical question as well, I know that I can increase memory, but what if json size is 3GB.

I'm asking if there is a library that would count all of the {} symbols and allow me to start for example at level 1, object 999999, (no matter where it is in the file and how much hierarhcy there was before) and decode starting from there object and/or subobject at a time

Comment: Did you try to enable the second parameter (`bool $assoc = false`) of the `json_decode` function ? It will store the json into a simple array instead of object, that could save some memory..

Comment: If this is not sufficient, I think that you have to write your own simple parser (coverring your need, not necessary extra complex JSON) because it seems that there is no a PHP implementation of SAX JSON parser