# PHP: Memory Optimizing Inbound Mail

Tags: php, json, base64, inbound

In my PHP application, I receive mails using [Postmarks's](http://postmarkapp.com) inbound hook. This service receives the mail and sends it JSON encoded to a URL on my server, which works fine.

The issue I have is, when the mail has attachments with more than 10MB.

Which results in

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 104857600 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 1821693 bytes)

What I'm doing in this line is:

```
$in = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

I have two questions:

1. Is there a way to do this more memory efficient?
2. Why is it failing for 10MB mails, where the memory limit is actually 100MB? Does Base64 + JSON encoding produce an overhead which is 10 times bigger than the original size?

**Edit after debuging with memory_get_usage()**:

```
Script start
47MB memory usage.
$in = file_get_contents("php://input");
63MB memory usage.
json_decode($in);
PHP terminates, due to memory size exhausted.
```

It is interesting, that the script already starts with a memory usage of 47MB, without issuing any command. I guess this is due to the large input data? Maybe because PHP stores it in $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA?

Is there any php.ini directive I could use, to let PHP create less variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

e-mail attachments are stored as base64, so actual e-mail body will be about 2 times bigger, so we have 20mb

json_encode (at senders side) also can add base64 overhead, so we can have about 40mb for single file_get_contents call, then json_decode will need about 20mb, add some local variables, and at least 1 loop - and 100mb is exhausted

I suggest you to read about: [memory_get_usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php) - use it to trace where php allocates memory

then use [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) and [gc_collect_cycles](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php)

**UPDATE:**
I'm not sure why json_decode needs so much memory (maybe some bug, update php?), anyway in php.ini

```
register_globals = off
register_long_arrays = Off
register_argc_argv = Off
auto_globals_jit = On
always_populate_raw_post_data = Off
```

You 2nd question: [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

> Thus, the actual length of MIME-compliant Base64-encoded binary data is usually about 137% of the original data length

JSON should not add big overhead, but additional encoding of mail body into json could probably use base64 again

Comment: Nice. I have not used `memory_get_usage` so far, but i will use it from now on, when i will have the chance. Up vote from me.

Comment: Thanks for the debugging hint with memory_get_usage. +1 I just updated my question with the debugging results.

Comment: PHP Version is 5.4.9. I managed to decrease the initial memory size a little (from 47MB to 31MB) by unsetting all global variables after script start. I guess thats all I can do, besides increasing the memory limit. unset($GLOBALS);
unset($_SERVER);
unset($_GET);
unset($_POST);
unset($_FILES);
unset($_REQUEST);
unset($_ENV);
unset($_COOKIE);
unset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
unset($http_response_header);
unset($argc);
unset($argv);
gc_collect_cycles();

Comment: @JochenJung look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077870/serial-json-decode-due-to-memory-limit maybe you can go with your own JSON parser, as you know that format is fixed?